# C Counting Tokens

Tags: c, counting, token

In each of the following statements, what are the tokens?

a. x = y +++ 3;
`x, =, y, ++, +, 3, ; 7 tokens`
b. a+=c*=(d+-2)>>5&3;
`a, +=, c, *=, (, d, +, -, 2, ), >>, 5, &, 3, ; 15 tokens`

For each, state whether it is a syntactically correct expression.
a. x+++y
`x, ++, +, y. Yes.`
b. x+++++y
`x, ++, ++, +, y. No.`

Just wondering if I'm counting tokens the right way. I wasn't sure if parenthesis are counted as separate tokens or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your proposed answers are correct.  Parentheses are tokens - in the C grammer, they're one of a class of tokens called *punctuators*.